# R Kable: Rotating Text in Column Grouping

Tags: r, latex, kable

I would like to wrap and rotate column HEADER headings in a kable-latex table.  I can control the width of the column using column spec, but I need to group columns in my table with a header, and it is the names in the header that I want to rotate and wrap.  A very basic example of my table is below.

```
example <- data.frame(name="testname", score1=3, score2=2, score3=0)

table <- kable(example, format="latex", escape = F) %>%   
column_spec(1:4, width = "5em") %>%   
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Rhyme Product" = 2, "Sound ID Middle" = 1)) %>%   add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Exploring Words" = 2, "Early Skills" = 1), bold = T)
```

I would like to flip the first set of column groupings (Rhyme Product and Sound ID Middle) on their side (angle = -45) and wrap the text on two separate lines taking up a lot less space.  Is this possible?

Comment: at this point, even just wrapping the text in the grouping columns names would do

Comment: Since you're using `kableExtra` to get these functions (that would be important to have noted in your post), look at the `kableExtra` vignette on Latex tables. Rotated header labels are on page 11

Answer (score 1):

This one is a pretty simple fix. I'm surprised no one has answered it over the years. One possibility is that the setting did not exist when this question was answered.

To add the line breaks, add a `\n` to the column names where you would like the breaks to be. To rotate, add `angle = "-45"` to the add_header_above line you would like to modify. See the code below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

example <- data.frame(name="testname", score1=3, score2=2, score3=0)

table <- kable(example, format="latex", escape = F) %>%   
  column_spec(1:4, width = "5em") %>%   
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Rhyme \nProduct" = 2, "Sound ID \nMiddle" = 1), angle = "-45") %>%   
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Exploring Words" = 2, "Early Skills" = 1), bold = T)

table
```

[Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46pnz.png)

Interestingly enough, the align argument accepts a vector of angles (i.e `align = c("-45", "90")`) to apply to each column. This is also true for row_spec. I have not seen anyone talking about this, nor is it anywhere in the documentation. It is really useful, however.